# New Age Armor Materials

Tags: science-based, materials, armors

In my world, high velocity projectile weapons have become obsolete due to a shield/forcefield that can nullify and deflect projectiles traveling at, or above supersonic speed (EDIT: Firearms are defunct, and obsolete. As such Sub-sonic ammunition for Firearms does not exist). As a result they have adopted martial weapons akin to those of medieval ages and have donned armour to protect against melee and ranged (Bow, Crossbow) aggressors.

The question is what materials and composition would lightweight (such as Textile) and heavy armour (Such as plate and leather) be made from?

- The armour would have to protect against slashing, stabbing/piercing,
  and blunt force trauma (Light armour able to protect enough to
  have moderate injuries, and plate enough to be able to have no to
  minor injuries)
- It would not have to protect against supersonic projectiles or energy
  weapons (EDIT: Subsonic ammunition used by firearms is defunct and
  does not play a role in armour materials and compososition)
- Complex materials can be used due to synthesisation (Machine that can
  synthesise materials), but complex processes cannot be used due to
  lack of infrastructure (Must be able to be made, worked, and
  repaired by hand like that of an armour-smith)
- Materials that can be used cannot be mythical/fictional, and must
  exist in this current day as at least a working prototype.
- Armour must not exceed 50kg (110 lbs)
- Armour would be used in everyday use and must be able to be repaired
  in a short amount of time (maximum of 5 days labour @ 8 hours a day)
- Abundant and easily obtainable materials would be preferred to keep
  costs down

Comment: Much of our modern bullet-proof knife-proof gear would work fine in this scenario. I'm not sure how much of it would be eliminated by your "lack of infrastructure" constraint. At least some of it is woven, but I'm under the impression at least some of it pretty much requires machine weaving to get it as tight as is needed for its job.

Comment: @Ed Grimm Fair point, lack of infrastructure would be specialized machinery necessary to create and a handle a specific material. A mechanical loom would be fine as it can handle a large array of textiles necessary for clothing, fabrics, etc.

Comment: Medieval armour? By the way, the premise of your question was just hilarious: super advanced civilization returns to stone age because bored.

Comment: @NofP Haha, not quite. It is set in a post apocalyptic time where they are attempting to slowly rebuild. They simply do not have the infrastructure, skills, or man-power at the present to come back to the modern age, they're only focusing on the necessities; medicine, education, resource management, defence, etc.

Comment: You need a better reason than a force field. If something stopped supersonic bullets, they switch to subsonic rounds. You can buy these off the shelf right now. Nobody is going to buy a sword.

Comment: And where would you expect to find mass produced gun-powder in a post apocalyptic world? Ammo reserves have been wiped out through a war of attrition, they do not have the infrastructure to make it. And then why would waste resources on something like gunpowder, when you could poor those resources into forges that can create and process metal for building, defence, vehicles, etc.

Comment: Are you the same user who posted this https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/138934/30492 few hours ago? If so, consider merging the two accounts, it's easier for you to track all your content and reputation

Comment: @L.Dutch I am, I didn’t know that was possible; i’ll Look into it. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @LucasA. Gunpowder consists of 3 common ingredients, 2 of which (Carbon and Sulphur) are **literally** among the 5 most common materials on the planet.  Grind them up, mix them together (optionally with water or alcohol to dampen them), then force it through a sieve and let it dry.  Lead casting to produce bullets is easier than forging chainmail.  Any "large settlement" could *easily* produce their own gunpowder and ammo with the right ingredients - even if only for old-fashioned flintlocks and the like.

Comment: Wait, you're saying they _can_ build forcefields and antigravity engines, but firearms are too complex?

Comment: Not to be a stick in the mud, but [subsonic rifle loads exist](https://www.americanhunter.org/articles/2018/3/19/top-6-subsonic-22-lr-loads-for-small-game-hunting/) and would quickly become popular in your world.  It's difficult creating a "crossbow in the times of guns" story because people are very good at finding creative ways of using "boom!" to kill people.  Herbert did it in *Dune* by making the forcfield almost impervious to the thrust of a knife, making all projectile weapons useless against them.

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of what amounts to arguing semantics here, instead of addressing the spirit of the question.  I believe the point is that an existing technology prevents fire-arm weapon use (anything faster than a bow or crossbow), so armor technology reverts appropriately to defending against the remaining weapons options (melee, bow and crossbow) instead.  I don't think modern firearm armor would be effective at all against blunt force weapons.  The ceramics would shatter on the first blow, making them useless on the next, and steel would either be prohibitively heavy or lack coverage

Comment: @Dalila Thank you for the addressing that Dalila, I was beginning to get frustrated at getting poked with sticks rather than answering the question.

Comment: @Deolater It's not that they can't, but they won't waste resources on something that brought humanity to it's knees. They also don't have any guns, they haven't been manufactured in century's.

Comment: It's a widespread problem on this site.  You should probably try to use what I said to edit your question to more clearly indicate those intended requirements to put a more complete stop to it on this question.  Unfortunately, I don't have the knowledge needed, in this particular field, to provide a complete answer to your question myself.  It's actually one that I've considered asking, but have yet to find a way to do it while avoiding this same nitpicking.  Your's is the best attempt I've seen so far to the question I, myself, would like to ask .

Comment: @Dalila I have taken your advice and edited the post to specify that firearms are not existent.

Comment: one thing your force field won't help with is chemical weapons. chlorine gas, mustard gas, and napalm are not that hard to make.

Comment: It's tricky not to poke questions like these.  The issue is that combat rewards people pushing the rules.  If you have a shield which stops everything going faster than 300m/s, I'm going to invent a firearm with a 299.95m/s projectile so that I can kill you faster.  This reality is often sidestepped in fiction (especially fantasy), but it makes it hard for people to provide answers.  My recommendation would be to pick the weapons you want to deal with (and their specifics), and seek body armor that handles them, rather than simply excluding firearms and defefending vs "everything else."

Comment: Frank Herbert's shields from Dune are clearly the archtypal example of this.  They were so sensitive that they stopped *all* projectiles.  Indeed, they even would stop most melee weapons.  The result?  Entire schools of fighting arts were dedicated to answering the question of how can you move the knife into the field slow enough to not set it off, while fast enough to kill them before they killed you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at most armours from across the ages that had to deal with just that sort of weaponry. I'd say anything from late medieval up to more or less modern day.

That covers Ring Mail, Chain Mail, Leather Jerkins, Curasses, Plate (including chest, upper, and full), no armour, riot armour (such as used by police), and kevlar/ceramic armour as used in modern anti-gun armour.

So materials:

- no armour: well thats easy. Swashbucklers, pirates, and naval men at arms would prefer this option, as armour is a quick way to drown.
- Jerkins (and similar): Leather, padding such as cloth, and perhaps light metal work (studs and rings).
- Chain/Ring mail: Metal working, as by any local forge. Factories could mass produce it simply. Bronze, iron, steel, or harder metals suitable.
- Plate: Metal Working, as by any local forge. Usually custom made to fit the particular soldier, and easily repairable. Could be mass produced with common standard sizes, but would lose some protection due to ill-fit. Bronze, iron, steel, or harder metals suitable.
- Riot/Kevlar/Ceramic: Plastic/Ceramic + Fabric. No choice but to manufacture via factory. Fortunately mass producible and modular.

The particular warrior/soldier would face a trade off with each armour class. Obviously the better protection as afforded by Plate and Full Body Kevlar/Ceramic is offset by their relative weight. [Full Plate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plate_armour) in steel comes in around 25kg if well worked.

Similarly each armour class protects against only a subset of the possible weapons out there.

Comment: And what materials would you use? Steel is antiquated and surely we have better alloys to use.

Comment: Against what exactly? Steel is plenty strong against your average barbarian invader standing 6+ft who grew up lifting heavy sacks of grain everyday from when they were 6 till when they decided to go a pillaging with a sword. Perhaps a few well funded knights, who live near specialised factories, might be equipped with the rarer and harder to work titanium, or advanced alloys. The most dangerous weapons in the subsonic world are still bullets and crossbow bolts neither of which are terribly inconvenienced by armour. Kevlar/Ceramic can shrug off a few at best, but requires a deep supply chain.

Comment: Also Steel + Concrete is the modern building material of choice. Just look at the [Burj Khalifa](http://www.burjkhalifa.ae/en/index.aspx) it stands 828metres high. There is nothing antiquated about it. The most likely mix for steel is an iron/carbon/nitrogen mix which is reasonably strong while also being relatively simple to forge by hand.

Comment: Thanks for the information, this is the kind of answer I was looking for. Could modern alloys cut through steel though? And would titanium alloy be strong enough to act as armour?

Comment: @LucasA. Modern steels are still up there - [Mangalloy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mangalloy) is especially resistant to any cutting - and is *much* easier to work with or repair than Titanium, which needs to be handled in an inert atmosphere (argon or helium) because it is so reactive.  (Titanium even reacts with *nitrogen*)  A Titanium sword *could* cut Mangalloy - but only in slow scrapes, and it would require far more force than just swinging a sword could generate.

Comment: @LucasA. "Could modern alloys cut through steel though?"  At armor thicknesses, not sitting at a workbench with metal working tools? Not a chance.  You can puncture it with extreme forces like mace, war hammer, bullet, or bow or crossbow with very heavy draws.  But "cut" it with a weapon, during combat, no way, unless the weapon is a lightsaber, or the armor wearer is unconscious and the weapon is a hacksaw or cutting torch.  Modern allows don't increase armor strength or weapon effectiveness.  They improve things like weight and flexibility for the **same level** of offense or defense.

Comment: @Chronocidal Thank you for the help, very informative.

Comment: In regards to the composition side of the question, specifically to do with the light armour side of things; could a layer of a non-Newtonian fluid be used to absorb the energy of a blunt force over a larger area, decreasing the risk of serious injury?

Comment: Aluminum alloy exists, so you can get steel strength with even less weight and once heat treated has than enough strength.There are even aluminium steel alloys that preform better than titanium.  But the other big savings in weight will be modern padding, a large portion of the weight of plate armor is the heavy padding that had to be worn under them. Today we have  foams and bubble wrap.

Comment: @John That was actually my next question, would a metal foam/sponge also be beneficial to the armour composition?

Comment: Yes the padding is critical, there is no point bouncing the weapon off the armour if the force can still penetrate and damage our rather soft and squishy bodies. Infact most bullet damage has nothing to do with the bullet itself but the shockwave that travels through the body essentially tearing and liquefying it. Modern foams, and structural compositions like bubble wrap can provide similar or better protection here against swords/maces/etc. With modern meta-materials it might even be possible for the armour to deform in response to a blow, and reshape itself while on the battle field.

Comment: @LucasA. Foam would be very useful as padding, metal foams and CMF's less so, most of them only really shine against ballistics, although a metal foam  sandwiched between something like carbon fiber might perform very well but that kinda goes against the complex processing prohibition.

Comment: Normal armor is basically a plate of metal treated to be very close to spring steel, so as to absorb the maximum amount of energy without deforming (which could cause greater injury). Of course some energy is still transferred, without padding the armor does little except prevent piercing it still transfers the impact. that is why padding is essential. modern foams including bubble membranes are much better shock absorbers AND much lighter, on top of that many also breath better, which is good for reducing fatigue. look at modern helmets, a thin shell packed with foams.

Comment: @John Thank you for clearing that up for me.

Comment: @Kain0_0 What kind of materials can do that?

Comment: It is also worth mentioning modern clear plastic means you can have real eye protection without sacrificing field of view, which was a big problem with medieval helmets.

Comment: [stiffness](https://phys.org/news/2017-02-metamaterial-world-theoretical-bounds.html), [general background](https://e-archivo.uc3m.es/bitstream/handle/10016/25772/flexible_NRM_2017_ps.pdf), Unfortunately I cannot relocate the article i read on a meta-material that after being deformed by being struck recovered its shape when an voltage differential was applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting hairs - I'm assuming you are looking to protect a professional soldier and not a random attack by a street thug looking to steal enough money for his next fix.   It makes a difference.   IF you are looking to stop say an assassin you can design body armor to act like a vehicle air bag in a traffic accident that inflates at point of contact for blunt force and be made of light weight composite of ceramic / Kevlar mesh to stop higher velocity projectiles.  May leave wearer with a nasty bruise but alive and works in the split seconds needed before help arrives.  Its trashed after one use unless its modular but it would have to be sent back to factory or dealer for repair.  This would require the user (who could afford such equipment) to keep spares (plural) so as to never be without protection.  Ideal customer - diplomat. As for a professional soldier -can't think of anything modern that can stand up to repeat punishment and act like a Timex.  The best he or she can hope for is that the supply chain of whatever outfit they work for will have the necessary repair/replacement parts.  Failing that its revert back to more rudimentary armor as mentioned by others.