# Propulsion Systems

Tags: science-based, engineering, vehicles, fuels

In my world, 500 years in the future, my population fits anti-gravity engines to salvaged boats as a form of transport. These transports fly close to the Earth's surface and are powered by a highly efficient solar panel system rigged as sails.

I'm struggling to come up with a design to propel the boats along, and the only concept that I can think of is propellers driven by electric engines.

**Is there a more efficient/effective engine design that I can utilise?**

Limitations:

- Fossil Fuels are depleted, and cannot be used.
- The largest of transports being Cargo Ships must travel at a minimum of 25 knots, and the smallest at a minimum of 45 knots.
- Fuel sources required for the engine must be in abundant supply and easy to manufacture or contain or, if a reactor is required - able to be stationed onboard the vessel and be maintained by an engineer.
- The engine must run as cleanly as possible. (As few emissions as possible)

EDIT: This question has been flagged as a duplicate due to another question that I have asked in the past. I believe that this question is not a duplicate as I am looking for a propulsion system, not an anti-gravity engine that could propel my transports. (In this case they cannot due to how my anti-gravity engines work.)

Comment: *"Cargo ships must travel at a minimum of 25 knots":* you do realize that this makes them go three times as fast as our present cargo ships powered by burning fuel oil? No cargo ship ever has maintained an average speed of 25 knots: sailing ships couldn't, and steamers wouldn't because of the vast amounts of fuel required.

Comment: So usually the answer is "depends on what technology is available."  However, in this case, I see a discontinuity that gives me pause.  They have anti-gravity engines and ultra-efficient super-thin solar cells for sails, but they salvage boats to put them on instead of designing crafts built for the purpose?  I have a feeling there's a reason behind that, and the reason may dramatically affect which answer is best.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Airship Propulsion System](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/138934/airship-propulsion-system)

Comment: Please do not create multiple accounts to ask the same question.

Comment: I'm going to join @dot_Sp0T to close this as a duplicate, although the selected duplicate may not be the best choice.  We've had a [lot of questions about airship propulsion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=airship+propulsion).  This question is a duplicate of one or more of those questions.

Comment: @dot_Sp0T I did not create multiple accounts to ask the same question thanks. I asked the other question as a guest and then registered and it created a new user rather than that of the guest acc.

Comment: Duplicate issues aside, I'm not totally clear on what you want here.  The transports have sails right?  So alternate propulsion is needed?  And they can't use their anti-gravity engines for propulsion because...?  Also, are you asking about the fuel or the actual physical method of propulsion?  What kind of fuel do the anti-gravity engines use?  Why is this tagged as science-based if we're talking about anti-gravity engines?  The visual of your concept seems cool but the question needs work.

Comment: @Cyn Thanks for the grammar check!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> - Fossil Fuels are depleted, and cannot be used.
> - The largest of transports being Cargo Ships must travel at a minimum of 25 knots, and the smallest at a minimum of 45 knots.
> - Fuel sources required for the engine must be in abundant supply and easy to manufacture or contain, or if a reactor is required - able to be stationed onboard the vessel and be maintained by an engineer.
> - The engine run as cleanly as possible. (As little emissions as possible)

Hydrogen powered jet engines.

In respective order to each requirement:

- Not fossils;
- More powerful than diesel, and most other fuels. This is literally  rocket fuel. So you may go much faster or farther for the same amount of fuel mass;
- Just electrolyze water. About 0.0003% of the mass of the planet is just oceans. You may use nuclear plants power to break water into fuel and oxidizer at large scale, serving millions of vehicles regionally - or car-sized and larger vessels may use small, solar powered electrolyzers (might take days to refill a tank in this way, though).
- Your exhaust is literally steam.

Comment: The OP wanted low/no emissions.  Your plan spews Dihydrogen Monoxide everywhere!!!!

Comment: @ShadoCat Not the dreaded Dihydrogen Monoxide, it will kill us all one day!

Comment: @Renan For curiosities sake, once the water has been electrolysed can it be used as drinking water, or used in Agriculture? In places of water scarcity its quite valuable.

Comment: @LucasA., The water gets ripped into the two gasses when it is separated.  However, if you can condense the waste steam from burning it, that is as close to chemically pure water as you are going to get.

Comment: @LucasA. adding to what ShadoCat said: that water is so pure it may actually harm living beings due to osmosis. You may need to add salts to it.

Comment: @LucasA., Running the water through a "sand filter" should fix the too pure water issue.  Just change the sand frequently to have a fresh supply of dissolvables.

Comment: @LucasA. considering the steam produced is ejected out the back, you don't get to hold onto it. But that said, flying over arid regions could potentially increase their rainfall - and by the time it's raining, it's no longer the toxicly pure water that you propelled your craft forward with.

Comment: @Renan I’ve given this one to you, i’m A bit biased  because I love steampunk and it would fit very well thematically.

Answer (score 5):

From OP. /and are powered by sails/

**They have sails!**

I know you are using your sails as solar panels which is excellent.  They can still be regular sails.  Boats have a long history of successfully being propelled by sails.

A problem with steering a sail airship is lack of contact with the water.  Regular sailboats have a rudder and I am not sure that will work 100% in the air.   You could have a super long blade like air keel.

If you are wind powered that leaves open the question of what you are using your electricity to do.  Keg fridge?

Comment: Windspeeds at high altitdue do reach hundreds of mph, so sails might work. Also airplanes do have rudders and so do airships.

Comment: You can steer with electric propellers. Some solar panels and batteries, and tail propellers line a helicooter and you are set.

Comment: I guess the keel is the main problem, as without it, you can only move in the general direction the wind does. But you could make the keel be part of the way the anti-gravity engine works. Say instead of generating lift (which you could then use for propulsion anyway), it just disables movement in certain directions. For antigravity, you disable up and down movement and for a keel-like effect, you simply additionally disable left and right movement.

Comment: A keel and a rudder does nothing when there's not a significant movement differential between what you are on and what you're in. Using wind to power your travels while you're entirely airborne means you move with the wind. Something like mlk's variant engine would allow one to be able to tack, but anti-grav would not be an appropriate name for something that worked like that. Also, the electricity would certainly be used to power anti-grav engines or mlk's thing.

Comment: Sails only work because a ship is at the interface between two different fluid media. A floating ship is functionally the same as a balloon, and no sail will do anything to propel it.

Comment: @Thucydides - a sail would increase surface area, and get you up to speed faster.

Answer (score 5):

> In my world, 500 years in the future; my population fit anti-gravity engines to salvaged boats as a form of transport

Use your anti-grav engines.

Gravity exerts a force on your sail-ships towards the center of the earth. In order for your ships to fly the anti-gravity engines must exert some force in the opposite direction. To move forward just add another engine that is 90° rotated.

Comment: I'd go for this. To maintain the constant low altitude the "anti-gravity" would actually be a repulsor that pushes on the ground below. If it can be balanced enough to be stable it can also be tilted enough to provide forward thrust.

Answer (score 1):

Not long a go a [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-018-0707-9.epdf?referrer_access_token=ywHsmqjVsrW5y3uduJhnt9RgN0jAjWel9jnR3ZoTv0O8jeS1MYPanuSpZ5pCO_VtFgGXGKuDUcpRuvuwHR0lUMmuswyIDvDwrGMe2BOz4KAgjXV9tTWSzlnz6cXdsrtmEkyDhz7Q99TlHUfo5OUOBkfPKIC6Kbd5kogYdb-5heZZ28-VRsUm9UO9rqrof81Ec8OEg72VNKMOjLTGvD53qNYeE0ZzdHU9qRCiPKX2FgiRcyxlqiV4radOaSUqRTGuaxl57aqUNd4DbFumC7jcTu28ZPAc-OUSbWnSH5Bms-c%3D) was released with the concept of an solid state propulsion for aeroplanes.

It works by creating a electical field in the wings, as they contain high-voltage electrodes. Nitrogen in the air gets ionized by the electic field and transports the charge from the front of the wing to the back of it. By that, the Nitrogen can collide with the rest of the air and pushes the air backwards, creating a backwards force and thus propels the aeroplane forward.

Biggest Problem might be to get the voltage to create enough propulsion for bigger ships, but else this is as carbon neutral as it gets.

Comment: Or, there could be propellers that push air backwards as they rotate; I don't know where to get the torque from yet, but as for the lift generated on the propeller blades, it's the cleanest tech you could ever dream up! ;)